# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Test1'

Tags: c#, path, directory

I'm trying to read a list of directories from an xml document and store them into a list, which then I'll get the subdirectories for. I'm testing this and I'm able to get the directories from the xml document, but when I try to get the subdirectories, I get the following error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Test1'. I've looked on other similar answers posted here but haven't been able to find a way to solve my problem. I've tried using forward slashes and back slashes, with and without the colon, still no luck.

Here's the XML

```
<Options>
<Directories>
<Directory>C:/Test1/</Directory>
<Directory>C:/Test2/</Directory>
<Directory>C:/Test3/</Directory>
</Directories>
<DeleteTime>30</DeleteTime>
</Options>
```

Here's my c# code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declaring variables for use later
            List<string> directories = new List<string>();
            List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();


            //Load Directories from XML
            XElement Options = XElement.Load("C:/Directories.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> DirList =
                from dir in Options.Descendants("Directory")
                select dir;
            foreach (XElement dirName in DirList)
            {
                directories.Add((string)dirName);
            }


            //Converting XML strings to Directories and adding all subfolders over 30 seconds old to a delete list
            foreach (var directory in directories)
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirItem = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                var folderList = dirItem.GetDirectories();
                Console.WriteLine(folderList);
            }
}
```

Comment: Could you also show the folders on the C drive were the code is running.  Maybe a image or something to show the folders exist with the same capitalization.

Comment: It was permission related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and setup the directory structure described by it and it all works for me.

This only thing I did was change all the forward slashes to back slashes.

```
    <Options>
<Directories>
<Directory>C:\Test1\</Directory>
<Directory>C:\Test2\</Directory>
<Directory>C:\Test3\</Directory>
</Directories>
<DeleteTime>30</DeleteTime>
</Options>
```

And the C#:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declaring variables for use later
            List<string> directories = new List<string>();
            List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();


            //Load Directories from XML
            XElement Options = XElement.Load(@"C:\Directories.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> DirList =
                from dir in Options.Descendants("Directory")
                select dir;
            foreach (XElement dirName in DirList)
            {
                directories.Add((string)dirName);
            }


            //Converting XML strings to Directories and adding all subfolders over 30 seconds old to a delete list
            foreach (var directory in directories)
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirItem = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                var folderList = dirItem.GetDirectories();
                Console.WriteLine(folderList);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd suggest that you check and make sure the process has rights to see the directory and that you aren't accidentally treating the back slashes as escape characters instead of a file path.  In my example I used the @ to avoid this.